# OpenCV Circle mask anti-aliasing

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV to overlay two images together.

Input 1 background (b.jpg):

[image: background]

Input 2 foreground (f.jpg):

[image: foreground]

Desired output:

[image]

Real output:

[image]

The idea is to overlay **circular part** of foreground onto background.

I'm using the code:

```cpp
Mat background = imread("b.jpg");
Mat foreground = imread("f.jpg");
Mat mask{foreground.size(), foreground.type(), Scalar::all(0)};
circle(mask, Point{foreground.cols / 2, foreground.rows / 2}, foreground.cols / 2 - 10, Scalar::all(255), -1, CV_AA);
imwrite("mask.jpg", mask);
foreground.copyTo(background, mask);
imwrite("overlay.jpg", background);
```

For the mask itself, I can see a perfect circle draw with very smooth edge.

[image]

But as soon as I call copyTo with the circular mask. The resulting image has abrupt edges and seems the anti-aliasing part is completely missing.

Is there a way to make the copyTo honoring the anti-aliasing fact? Or there is an easier way to achieve the same output?

Comment: Try to save in bmp instead of jpg?

Comment: Thanks @Ema, but bmp didn't help.

Comment: The smooth image you're looking at is grayscale. If you zoom in on the perimeter of the circle, you will see gray pixels in between the white pixels that make the circle appear smooth. Masks are, by definition, binary. The gray pixels are not there to smooth the appearance of the edges. You cannot do what you are attempting to do with a simple binary image. However, depending on your source image, you may be able to achieve decent results using alpha blending.

Comment: Inspired by @beaker's comment, the image got a lot smoother by adding alpha channel to the input image.